# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Module._compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to running following Node JS code for My server

but it gives err on line 74 but the all code is finished on line 72

My code is

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 4004,
    publicDir = process.argv[2] || __dirname + '/public';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;


  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/prisync', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to Database");

//Show homepage
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/index.html");
  console.log("shubham ");
});
app.get("/index/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/index.html");
  console.log("shubham ");
});

app.get("/search", function (req, res){
  console.log("shubham batra");
   var pro_name = req.query.name;
   var pro_code = req.query.code;
   var pro_category = req.query.category;
   var pro_brand = req.query.brand;

   console.log(name);
   console.log(code);
   console.log(category);
   console.log(brand);



    var documen = {name:pro_name, code:pro_code , category:pro_category, brand:pro_brand };

  //insert record
  db.collection('urlinfo').insert(documen, function(err, records) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Record added as "+records[0]._id);
  });

   //res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
  console.log(res.body);
  res.redirect("/index.html");
});
app.use(errorHandler({
  dumpExceptions: true,
  showStack: true
}));
//Search page
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use(errorHandler({
  dumpExceptions: true,
  showStack: true
}));

console.log("Server showing %s listening at http://%s:%s", publicDir, hostname, port);
app.listen(port);
```

while I try to run this code it is giving following error :

> ```
> shubham@shubham-pc:~/Music/server$ nodejs server.js 
>
> /home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/server.js:74 });
>     SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:935:3
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed a code block properly:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/prisync', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to Database");
  // The rest of your code that needs `db` should go here
});
```